# Is there a way to run a script on a Linux machine when master is changed in a git repo?

Tags: bash, git, discord.js, raspberry-pi3

I have a raspberry pi running Ubuntu that I am using to host a discord bot. I was trying to figure out if there is any way to detect when master of the bot's code repository was changed and then run a script on the pi to stop the bot, pull the changes and then restart it? I have written the script already I'm just not sure how to trigger it.

Comment: That's the kind of task `cronjobs` are made for.

Comment: You can poll the repository (e.g., run `git pull` and see if the value of `HEAD` changes). Depending on where your repository lives you may also be able to take advantage of web hooks or some other event to receive a notification when it changes.

Comment: This is what [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) are made for.

Comment: What git server do you use?

Answer (score 0):

There are a two main solutions to this - cronjobs and webhooks. A cronjob is likely easiest, but webhooks give more external control.

### Cronjobs

A cronjob will run a script at a given interval. If you set a cronjob on the pi to run `git fetch` it will update the refs of the remotes. You can then do `git rev-parse <branch>` to get the commmit ID of a given branch. So in bash you can do:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
REMOTE=origin
BRANCH=master
git fetch
if [[ "$(git rev-parse $BRANCH)" != "$(git rev-parse "$REMOTE/$BRANCH")" ]]; then
  # Run your script
fi
```

### Webhooks

If you are hosting your code on a major platform - like GitLab, GitHub, or BitBucket - it likely supports webhooks to do this. A webhook is where you give the repo host a URL which they will call when a certain event happens. If you are using somebody else's repository, you can make a fork that mirrors theirs and add the webhook to your fork.

This requires your pi to be accessible from the web and running an HTTP server, you will either need a static IP address or a DDNS service for this to work.